# Tweepy.streamingを用いたプログラムでツイートの取得をタイムラインで取得したい

Tags: python, twitter

プログラム内容

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream

consumer_key = ""#引用符の中にconsumer_keyの情報を記述する
consumer_secret = ""#引用符の中にconsumer_secretの情報を記述する

access_token = ""#引用符の中にaccess_tokenの情報を記述する
access_token_secret = ""#引用符の中にaccess_token_secretの情報を記述する

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        if data.startswith("{"):
            print data
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    stream = Stream(auth, l)
    stream.filter(track = [u"日本"])#検索する場合
    if 'stream' in stream:
        print stream['text'].encode('utf-8')
#    stream.sample()#ツイートのランダムサンプリングを取得する場合
#    stream.userstream()#タイムラインを取得する場合
```

実行結果

```
[root@localhost デスクトップ]# python intento.py
{"created_at":"Thu Sep 22 08:01:36 +0000 2016","id":778866827346714624,"id_str":"778866827346714624","text":"RT @RealOviedo: \u00a1Buenos d\u00edas, oviedistas! S\u00ed, hoy jugamos en casa (20h) #RealOviedoReus https:\/\/t.co\/qKRRBF2eot","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/android\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for Android\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":714885097,"id_str":"714885097","name":"Gorkitta","screen_name":"gorka_laporte","location":null,"url":null,"description":"Zu zara nagusia.\nREAL OVIEDO \u2764\u2764 ATHLETIC CLUB","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":368,"friends_count":278,"listed_count":11,"favourites_count":2643,"statuses_count":15851,"created_at":"Tue Jul 24 20:30:59 +0000 2012","utc_offset":12600,"time_zone":"Tehran
```

上記のプログラムをtextで表示して欲しいのですがうまくいきません。
例えば`＠saksa 日本最高だ！`　のようにtextで表示して欲しいです。
もしやり方がわかる方いれば、教えていただけるとありがたいです
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: しっかり読んでいないので申し訳ないのですが，`if 'stream' in stream:` が真になることはなさそうな気がします．ここで `print` されているのは多分 `StdOutListener.on_data` の働きなので，いじるならそこかと思います．

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

`on_data`の`data`のデータ形式は複数あるのでしょうか。JSONが来た時だけ反応するようにするなら、次のようにすれば良いと思います。

```
import json
def on_data(self, data):
    try:
       payload = json.loads(data)
       print payload.get('text')
       return True
    except:
       pass
    return False
```